# Kubernetes: Map multiple Services to 1 external endpoint

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes Cluster running and have multiple Services fronting a few Pods. When I expose a each service as a LoadBalancer, it creates an unique endpoint for Public consumption. Is there a way to configure this to expose 1 common endpoint and then have Filters that redirect traffic to the correct Pod base on request Path?
e,g
External endpoint: www.common-domain/v1/api/

Service 1: /account
Pods 1: account-related-pods

Service 2: /customer
Pods 2: customer-related-pods

Service 3: /profile
Pods 3: profile-related-pods

Then a request comes in for "www.common-domain/v1/api/account", it should invoke the account-related-pods.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like ingress

Running an ingress controller can server as a frontend for routing to different services based on http rules
http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/

And here are the docs on spinning up an nginx ingress controller
https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers